# view doesn't detect error in passed in model object

Tags: grails, gsp

The code in controller is as follows:

```
for(o in options){

    if(o){

        if(!o.isInteger()){

            don.errors.reject("The value was not integer")

            render(view: "editdonation", model: [id:id, donation:don])
            return

        }

        don.addToDenominations(o.toInteger())

    }

}
```

I intentionally pass in invalid input so that the don.errors.reject() code is executed.

The editdonation.gsp has the following code to print the error in the donation object.

```
<ul class="inline-errors" role="alert">

        <g:hasErrors bean="${donation}">

                <div class="errors">

                         ok it has errors              

                </div>

         </g:hasErrors>     

    </ul>
```

Why is the view not displaying the error? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The [Errors.reject()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#reject-java.lang.String-) method expects an error code rather than an error description.

## Creating the error code

To create your own error code:

1. Edit the file *grails-app/i18n/message.properties*
2. Add a new line with your error code. Ex: **option.donation.notinteger=The option value {0} was not an Integer**
3. Save the file *grails-app/i18n/message.properties*

## Using the error code

To use the error code, call `Errors.reject()` like this:

```
don.errors.reject('option.donation.notinteger', [o] as Object[], 'The value was not integer')
```

The code above passes the option to reject so that it can insert the value into the error message. And as required, it provides a fallback error message.

Comment: I have added the above entry in the message.properties file and also i have used in code in errors.reject() instead of message but yet i don't see any errors being rendered in the view page.